# Windows 10 Pro - how to install nvidia drivers manually

Tags: windows-10, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I have installed Windows 10 Pro and performed Windows Update. Nvidia driver installed by Windows is older than a driver which can be download from the Nvidia website. I know that after uninstalling Nvidia driver Windows installs it automatically again (older version). I have tried two ways to stop automatic Nvidia driver installation, unfortunately without success:

- advance system settings/hardware/device installation settings -
  switched to No
- Windows Update blocked using this [tool](https://www.sordum.org/9470/windows-update-blocker-v1-5/)

Do you know any other working solution for that problem ? I would like to install the newest Nvidia driver manually.

Comment: Have you tried just installing the newest driver from the Nvidia site (without uninstalling the Windows driver)?

Comment: Download the Driver from Nvidia and save it to a folder you can find easily, then execute the installer by double clicking it.

Comment: Is it ok to install the newer driver version without uninstalling the older version ?

Comment: @Irbis, Yes it is OK to install the newer driver without uninstalling the older one.

Comment: @Irbis Is this a laptop/desktop built by an OEM? OEMs usually heavily customize their discrete GPU drivers and as such, the generic drivers from the GPU manufacturer are generally not able to be used _(esp if it's a laptop)_ - the correct driver version would be the one the OEM offers on their driver download page for the PC, as using the generic drivers can affect functionality and potentially cause a loss of functionality of a OEM's custom features. _(Windows Update installs the most recent WHQL driver available for an installed component.)_

Answer (score 1):

The most simple method to update the driver is installing Nvidia Geforce Experience
https://www.nvidia.com/pt-br/geforce/geforce-experience/download/
After the install go to "drivers" and you can download the last version available.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [DDU](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/display-driver-uninstaller-ddu-v18021-released) (Display Driver Uninstaller) to uninstall your existing graphics driver completely
2. Download the nVidia [driver](https://www.nvidia.de/Download/index.aspx) you need
3. Execute the downloaded file.

   - It asks for a folder where to extract its files, and, after extraction, leave the automatic setup window open. From there, copy the extracted files wherever you want, then close the setup window (you now no longer need to extract the files again if needing to re-install).
4. To Install:

   - Launch `setup.exe`; or
   - Within the extracted folder, right-click the driver's `.inf` > "Install"; or
   - Via Device Manager

For non-experts, I recommend using `setup.exe` and skipping "GeForce Experience".

Answer (score -1):

I made this software to solve the headache of manual driver installation. The software is free and open source. It automates the whole process with a wizard. You just have to specify the .inf file and that's all!!!
Here is the link to download:
https://botien-driver-installer.sourceforge.io
https://sourceforge.net/projects/botien-driver-installer/files/BotienDriverInstaller-x64.exe/download

Comment: 1) Please note that attempting to promote your own software is not encouraged on Super User, which is probably why someone downvoted this. 2) You didn't mention that it needs Python to be installed. 3) Does it do anything that right-clicking on the .inf file and choosing "Install" doesn't do?